# Prove that $F$ is a functor between $C/c$ and $C$.

Tags: category-theory

I'm totally new in category theory and am using Awodey's Category theory.
He makes an example of a functor $F: C/c \to C$ defined so that $F(X \to C)=X$ and $F(a:(f:X \to C) \to (g:Y \to C))=a:X \to Y$.

Now I can see a commutative triangle goes to another commutative triangle by this functor; but to see the composition of arrows is preserved, I get confused. For instance suppose that $f:X \to C$, $f':Y \to C$ and $f'':Z \to C$ are three objects of $C/c$. Now let $a:f \to f'$ and $b:f' \to f''$ be arrows between them. By definition of the functor, then, I know which objects from $C$ go to which ones in $C/c$.

Furthermore, I know that both $F(b) \circ F(a)$ and $F(b \circ a)$ are both from $X$ to $Z$. But I'm not sure why they must be the same!
Obviously the equality holds if we have a restriction in the definition of a category like "arrows are unique between objects". But this restriction also fails to hold as we have the category of monoids.

So where does this confusion come from?

Comment: Do you know the definition of composition in the category $C/c$?

Comment: You mean it's no enough to know how the functor acts on objects and arrows of the initial category? All I know is that.

Comment: Well, how can you possibly check whether $F$ preserves composition if you don't even know what composition is?

Comment: And we should check if it (given that how it acts on obj and arr) preserves the composition. right?

Comment: Yes that's right by clarifying the definition of the composition, everything will be Ok!